# Why jpa binding enum parameter as varbinary

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Why jpa binding enum parameter as varbinary?

```java
@Query(value = "select * from person where skin in :skin",nativeQuery=true)
List<People> findInSkins(Skin[] skin);
```

Here is the log

```
Hibernate: select * from person where skin in (?, ?)
2019-11-12 18:59:57.282 TRACE 141600 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder : binding parameter [1] as [VARBINARY] - [Yellow]
2019-11-12 18:59:57.283 TRACE 141600 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder : binding parameter [2] as [VARBINARY] - [Black]
```

Comment: It always return []

Comment: It will return  correct result when i use hql not nativequery

Comment: What else should it do? SQL doesn't know about your Skin class.

Comment: public enum Skin{
        Yellow,Black,White;
    }

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. But I found no solution here...

Answer (score 1):

If you want `jpa` to bind it as a **String** you should use this decorator:

```
**@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)**
```